# i get wrong data with WebI report Filter

Tags: business-objects, webi

I created in crosstabe table:
[image: webi report result]

When I try to get only the customer who made trans more than 50 in total like the customer `222`, all the data less than 50 don't show up.

Example: customer `222` did two actions

1. `3/25/2018` with amount `209` gb,
2. `3/29/2018` with amount `14` gb,
   The sum of both is `223`.

I need to get all customers who made more than 50 actions in all days. When I try that by adding a filter the action in day `3/29/2018` is not shown and I get only the action in `3/25/2018`.

Comment: any help please

Comment: If you can include a SQL query it might help.  It sounds like your wanting to query based on the sum total?